# Renew/Extend Seaman's Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, south-african-citizens, visa-extensions

I need some advice/help with my Schengen visa renewal.

I am currently in France and will end my season on 31 October on my current boat. Afterwards I will be joining another boat in France on a new contract.

My visa is valid until March 2018 and I still have 80+ days left to stay within the Schengen area.

I would like to know if it is possible for me to renew my visa in Europe or do I need to travel back to South Africa, and is it possible to renew/lengthen my visa while mine is currently still valid and I have days left?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: seaman can generally get a visa at the border, with cooperation of the employer, for the purpose of joining our leaving a vessel.  But it sounds like your vessel may be operating entirely in French waters, or Schengen waters; is that the case?

Comment: Yes, the boat will mainly be in a schengen area..

Comment: I have never heard about getting a visa at the boarder? Not for south Africans at least...